# Drupal 8 Nginx error No such file or directory for any routes

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker, php7, drupal8

I'm running Drupal 8.1.2 on a Docker image of `Nginx + PHP7 + PHP 7 FPM` and it's linked to another Docker image of `PostgreSQL` both of them based from Alpine Linux.

After successfully running Drupal installation (on core/install.php url) and setting up website name, admin name and other details, it throws 404 right after I hit the submit button. I am only able to access `/update.php` URL.

### The [error log](https://github.com/dminca/dockerized-drupal/issues/40):

```
2016/06/17 16:32:49 [error] 11#0: *80 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2016/06/18 11:47:32 [error] 13#0: *40 open() "/var/www/html/user/1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/core/install.php?langcode=en&profile=minimal"
2016/06/18 11:29:00 [error] 170#0: *83 open() "/var/www/html/update.php/selection" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /update.php/selection HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/update.php"
2016/06/18 11:28:19 [error] 170#0: *83 open() "/var/www/html/node" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /node HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2016/06/18 11:28:19 [error] 170#0: *83 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /node HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

### The [nginx.conf](https://p.ngx.cc/9f)

```
server {
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Allow &#34;Well-Known URIs&#34; as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to &#34;hidden&#34; files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal &lt;= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal &gt;= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don&#39;t allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the &#39;.php&#39; appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php|selection$|add$|^/user/\d' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Security note: If you&#39;re running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have &#34;cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;&#34; in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal &lt;= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal &gt;= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal.
    location ~ ^/system/files/ { # For Drupal &gt;= 7
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

### The default.conf

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  _;

    root /var/www/html;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME          $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;    
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

### `/etc/nginx/` file tree

```
/etc # tree nginx      
nginx                  
├── conf.d             
│   └── default.conf   
├── default.d          
├── fastcgi.conf       
├── fastcgi_params     
├── koi-utf            
├── koi-win            
├── mime.types         
├── nginx.conf         
├── scgi_params        
├── uwsgi_params       
└── win-utf            

2 directories, 10 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding [this configuration](https://p.ngx.cc/c8) in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    server_name drupaldocker.com;
    root /var/www/html; ## <-- Your only path reference.

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal.
    location ~ ^/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

FastCGI was also getting **connection refused** if specified as `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;`.

The only downside I have now is that I can't download any modules/themes via the Extend section, but this is just a folder permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks like it is not valid for Drupal 8. According to https://pantheon.io/blog/update-your-nginx-config-drupal-8 article, Drupal 8 has some unusual paths that need to be covered separately in nginx configuration. The article should contain the information you need to fix the issues.

Comment: I've already applied those fixes, my conf is based from the [official nginx Drupal 8 recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/). I'm looking now into [skyred's conf](https://gist.github.com/skyred/4248423) to see what could work out ok

Comment: Well, I've applied what skyred suggested in [his conf](https://gist.github.com/skyred/4248423#file-insready-com) and it still throws 404 after it jumps to `/user/1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `try_files` wrong in the section

```
location / {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal &lt;= 6
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal &gt;= 7
}
```

The last argument of `try_files` is the "404" location. Id you edit it to

```
try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string =404;
```

it might work

Comment: I've tried it, and still throwing me 404 :(