# Nginx image header cache not updating

Tags: nginx, cache, http-headers

I have an image file at https://www.example.com/img/bart-had-a-groove.gif

And this is the only cache block in my site config, there is no caching settings in global nginx.conf.

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform, max-age=2628000";
}
```

Now, you can see my header is set to `Cache-Control "public, no-transform, max-age=2628000";`, but if you CURL the image e.g. `curl -X GET -I https://www.example.com/img/bart-had-a-groove.gif` you get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/gif
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.13.9
Content-Length: 771510
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 17:26:23 GMT
ETag: "58a7323f-bc5b6"
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: public
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 21:49:33 GMT
Expires: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 21:49:33 GMT
```

You can see that `Cache-Control: public` does not match the config. It's missing the `no-transform, max-age=2628000` part.

I run `systemctl stop nginx && systemctl start nginx && systemctl reload nginx` after every change.

**Update**
The rest of server block:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/;

  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name www.example.com;

  location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;    
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
    # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
    # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
    include fastcgi_params;
    # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # PHP 5 socket location.
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    # PHP 7 socket location.
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  #expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform, max-age=2628000";
}

  pagespeed on;
  # Needs to exist and be writable by nginx.  Use tmpfs for best performance.
  pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
  # Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
  # and no extraneous headers get set.
  location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
    add_header "" "";
  }
  location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
  location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: @Michael Hampton added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two correlating configuration directives, regarding the "Cache-Control" header (see below). I recommend to use only **add_header** as you appreciate the "no-transform" directive of the "Cache-Control" header.

**expires 1M;**

--> Will set header "Cache-Control" and "Expires".

[See documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires):

> Enables or disables adding or modifying the “Expires” and
>   “Cache-Control” response header ...

**add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform, max-age=2628000";**

--> Will manually set the "Cache-Control" header.

Comment: I tried that, it's not applying to the image. The header never change.

Comment: Turns out it has something to do with `pagespeed`. But not sure what, toggling it off and on after making changes to my header, it applies. You can see the rest of my config in original post.