# PHP and Nginx on docker, curl get Connection refused in php container

Tags: nginx, php, docker, web-server, curl

I am working in a local environment with docker.
I have an nginx web container and a php container which are in the same network.

I build the php container from my own dockerfile (with phpfpm and phpcli); and, the nginx I compose it in a docker-compose from the `nginx:stable` hub image.

I have 2 projects: a symfony(`http://i-r4y.kaiza.lh/`) and a drupal(`http://i-z4r4.kaiza.lh/`) which runs in it. and the symfony exposes an api which have to be consumed by the drupal. The problem is that an error when I call the symfony from the drupal `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to i-r4y.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused`

I thought it was a configuration of the symfony side api route; like it must be public or accept CORS etc ...

but **in the php container**, when I do curl either the symfony or drupal url, I have the same error.

```
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ curl http://i-r4y.kaiza.lh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to i-r4y.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ curl http://i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to i-z4r4.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused
```

I checked in the php container that the hosts are present in `/etc/hosts`

```
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ cat /etc/hosts | grep i-
127.0.0.1   i-r4y.kaiza.lh
127.0.0.1   i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  php7.4:
    build:
      context: ../../../dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: 7.4
    container_name: "kz-php74"
    hostname: "kz-php74"
    user: 1000:1000
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - "${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www"
    extra_hosts:
      - "i-r4y.kaiza.lh:127.0.0.1"
      - "i-z4r4.kaiza.lh:127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      - kz_local

  mysql:
    container_name: kz-mysql
    image: mariadb:10.4.0
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/.data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/config/mariadb/conf.d/custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - kz_local

  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: kz-web
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - kz_local

networks:
  kz_local:
    external: true
```

The nginx config of drupal:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name i-z4r4.kaiza.lh;

    root /var/www/i-z4r4/web;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        set $fastcgi_pass "kz-php74:9000";

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass $fastcgi_pass;
    }

  ...

}
```

For symfony:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name i-r4y.kaiza.lh;

    root /var/www/i-r4y/public;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        set $fastcgi_pass "kz-php74:9000";

        fastcgi_pass $fastcgi_pass;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }
...
}
```

will anyone have any idea why this is not working?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an alias in the network of the web container through which I can access from the php container.

```
...
  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    ....
    networks:
      kz_local:
        # To allow fetch (call, curl) from php container.
        aliases:
          - api.i-r4y.kaiza.lh
          - api.i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
...
```

and of course, I needed to add the url aliases in config nginx :

```
...
server_name i-z4r4.kaiza.lh api.i-z4r4.kaiza.lh;
...
```